# How to use the webservice-client classes generated with Eclipse?

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse, webservice-client, axis

I used eclipse Helios to create a Web Service Client for consuming an axis 1.4 web service.
It generated 2 packages:
1 - datamodel.
2 - client.

Inside client package there are 5 classes:
1- ServiceName
2- ServiceNameProxy
3- ServiceNameService
4- ServiceNameServiceLocator
5- ServiceNameSoapBindingStub

I need to Know what are these ? AND
How to call the web service methods with parameters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am **very** new to Web Services and I can't give a good explanation of *what* those classes are, but, I believe you can use the `Proxy` class to call the Web Service methods.

```
public class TestClient{
    public static void main(String []args){
        ServiceNameProxy proxy = new ServiceNameProxy();
        proxy.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/ServiceName/asdf");//defined in wsdl

        int i = proxy.webServiceMethod(new String(), new String());
    }
}
```

`webServiceMethod()` would be whatever the name of the method is defined in the service.

Comment: how to handle authentication when using proxy  I used stub and can set username and password

Comment: @Fahad please use punctuation.. I can't understand your comment

Comment: I had the same interrogation. Hey, Eclipse and Axis people, the generated Java classes miss Javadoc ! This answer works ! And the code is simple. :-) I was a little puzzled by the `setEndpoint` line, so let me precise this. The address passed here is the Web Service's address, not the address of the WSDL. The "asdf" bit and the comment `defined in wsdl` create more confusion than explanation.