# How to generate java classes from WSDL file

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl

I am working towards an android application. I need to use a web service. I have a wsdl file but I want to convert that into java so that I can use its functions in my Java programs. 
Is there any way of converting a wsdl file into Java?

Comment: supose that u have jdk 1.6 or higher go in cmd in the location you want to output the generated classes and in that location write:         wsimport -keep -verbose http ://myWsdlURL?wsdl

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you can use:

[Wsdl2java eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/)

With this all you will need is to supply the wsdl, and the client which is the Java classes will be automatically generated for you.

Comment: Will these java classes be supported in Android??

Comment: @Farhan Yes that will not make any difference.

Answer (score 12):

Just to generate the java classes from wsdl to me the best tool is "cxf wsdl2java". Its pretty simple and easy to use. I have found some complexities with some data type in axis2.
But unfortunately you can't use those client stub code in your android application because [android environment doesn't allow the "java/javax" package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902943/how-to-include-additional-javax-packages-in-android-app-with-eclipse) in compiling time unless you rename the package name.

And in the android.jar all the javax.* sources for web service consuming are not available. To resolve these I have developed this [WS Client Generation Tool](http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/) for android.

In background it uses "cxf wsdl2java" to generate the java client stub for android platform for you, And I have written some sources to consume the web service in a smarter way.

Just give the wsdl file location it will give you the sources and some library. you have to just put the sources and the libraries in your project. and you can just call it in some "method call fashion" just we do in our enterprise project, you don't need to know the namespace/soap action etc. For example, you have a service to login, what you need to do is :

```
LoginService service = new LoginService ( );
Login login = service.getLoginPort ( );
LoginServiceResponse resp = login.login ( "someUser", "somePass" );
```

And its fully open and free.

Comment: Can you tell me, in which jar file, I can see method support by this service, please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

jdk 6 comes with **wsimport** that u can use to create Java-classes from a WSDL. 
It also creates a Service-class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have **JAXB** installed
Go to the following directory **C:\Program Files\jaxb\bin**
open command window here

**> xjc -wsdl http://localhost/mywsdl/MyDWsdl.wsdl C:\Users\myname\Desktop**

**C:\Users\myname\Desktop** is the ouput folder you can change that to your preference

**http://localhost/mywsdl/MyDWsdl.wsdl** is the link to the WSDL

Answer (score 5):

You can use the eclipse plugin as suggested by Oscar earlier. Or if you are a command line person, you can use Apache Axis WSDL2Java tool from command prompt. You can find more details here http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html#WSDL2JavaReference

Answer (score 5):

i founded a great toool to auto parse and connect to web services

http://www.wsdl2code.com

http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/Example.aspx

```
 SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
     req = new Request();                     
     req.companyId = "1";
     req.userName = "userName";                                     
     req.password = "pas";
     Response response =    srv1.ServiceSample(req);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WSDL2JAVA Codegen **(or)** You can simply use the '**Web Service/WebServiceClient**' Wizard available in the Eclipse IDE.
Open the IDE and press 'Ctrl+N', selectfor '**Web Service/WebServiceClient**', specify the wsdl URL,  ouput folder and select finish.

It creates the complete source files that you would need.

Comment: Sir, I couldn't find webserviceclient in the eclipse.. can you please elaborate a bit more on that.. thnx

Comment: Sir, I can't see any web service or webserviceclient when I press Ctrl+N. am I missing some plugins??

Comment: What you need is 'org.eclipse.jst.ws'. Download links>> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/galileor I have worked with Eclipse 3.3 to 3.6, and Web Services is available in 3.3, but not 3.6.

Comment: [Using Eclipse's Web Service Client wizard](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf) is what I have done, [thanks to this nice guide](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf). Unexplained errors of access to the WDSL. But the Java classes are generated ! Now, how to use them ? I want to call Java methods that connect to the Web Service and perform WS operations.

Comment: @Nicolas: Check this ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654517/creating-client-for-web-service/8654927#8654927

Comment: @Anuj — Thank you, but this does not fit my generated Java classes. But [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4149405/1824094) is promising. Hey, Eclipse and Axis people, the generated Java classes miss Javadoc !

Comment: Exactly the same. The one I suggested does the same, only thing is that I haven't explained  them well :P

Comment: Answer : [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4149405/1824094) works ! And the code is simple. :-)